# How to take two different rdlc file in one pdf

Tags: .net, pdf, report, rdlc

I designed Six rdlc reports in my application. When the user select the check box of six reports and select the format like PDF,Excel or Word then i want to download in one PDF. If its one I can download the single PDF file. If it two or three means then I want to download two or three PDF in one.

Comment: Add them all as subreports in one report and add parameters to that main report to toggle subreport's visibility.

Comment: you could generate each one individually to pdf files then use a tool like iTextSharp to merge the pdf files together. This also give the ability to use pdf files generated from other sources too.